# Spring GWT http request timeout

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, spring-mvc, timeout

I'm using GWT and Spring controller to manage http traffic. Some of the requests may take long time, but I want to kill requests when exceeds the given time.

How can I configure spring with timeout. I use also `Apache Tomcat 7.0`. I tried to insrease max thread on tomcat but with a time tomcat works slowly because request threads not die.

Comment: do you mean 'maxThread = "500"'?

Comment: i cant ask a question without code example :)) sorry

Comment: http requests may take 4-5 hour. but i dont want to exceed 1 hour.

Comment: Are you using async support? https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mode/archive/2008/12/asynchronous_su.html

Comment: yes i'm using asynchronous services

Answer (score 0):

Make your Async interface return com.google.gwt.http.client.Request instance and use a timer to cancel the request. Not sure what you mean about the Spring controller.

```
com.google.gwt.http.client.Request

An HTTP request that is waiting for a response. Requests can be queried for their pending status or they can be canceled
```